# smbus access in pcie under windows

Tags: pci, pci-e, smbus

I'm looking for a way to control smbus line in PCIe slot of my PC. There's some device connected via PCIe in that slot. And I wanna access it via the SMBus line under Windows, but cannot find any API to use for that.

Can you suggest me how to do that please?

Answer (score 0):

In linux/unix env, there has i2c_tools, which directly access to SMBus by user state applications. But in windows, i also looking for some solutions to do this.